# Constructing a new graph. G'. What does it mean v ∈ S_{i+1}?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, notation

> John lives in a city whose streets has the same length. His apartment is located at a specified node H. John need to do his  errands where he visits each of k different shop in order. However, each store have more than one location in his city. More particularly, for each 1 ≤ i ≤ k there is a set $S_{i}$ of vertices at which a branch of the $i^{th}$ shop is located (you can assume that the $S_{i}$ are disjoint). Construct a new graph G' as following:
>
> Create a new graph G' whose nodes are given by both a node of G,
>   representing John’s current location, and a number 0 ≤ i ≤ k, giving the number of stops that John has successfully made. In particular, the vertices of G' are exactly given by (v, i) with v ∈ Node and i ∈ {0, 1,..., k}.  Edges in G' are between (u, i) and (v, i) if (u, v) is an edge of G, or between (u, i) and (v, i + 1) if (u, v) is an edge of G and v ∈ $S_{i+1}$.

**What does it really mean by "between (u,i) and (v,i+1) if (u,v) is an edge of G and V v ∈ $S_{i+1}$"?**

Let's say we have simple graph G as below:
[image]

Here is my attempt of constructing the new graph G'.

How many new nodes do we need to make, 3  or 4 copies? I only make 3 so far since there are only 3 errands. Please let me know if my G' is correct. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The vertices of $G'$ are exactly given by $(v, i)$ with $v\in Nodes$ and $i \in \{0, 1,\cdots, k\}$.  Edges in $G'$ are between $(u, i)$ and $(v, i)$ if $(u, v)$ is an edge of $G$, or between $(u, i)$ and $(v, i + 1)$ if $(u, v)$ is an edge of $G$ and $v\in S_{i+1}.$

We know $Nodes$ are 6 nodes, i.e., $H, B1, B2, Bus, P, M$ and $k=3$ as there are three kinds of shops, i.e., bank, post office and movie where $S_1$ is the set of banks, $S_2$ post offices and $S_3$ movies.

There are 24 vertices of $G'$
$$\begin{align}
(H,0),(B1,0), (B2,0), (Bus,0), (P,0), (M,0), \\
(H,1),(B1,1), (B2,1), (Bus,1), (P,1), (M,1), \\
(H,2),(B1,2), (B2,2), (Bus,2), (P,2), (M,2), \\
(H,3),(B1,3), (B2,3), (Bus,3), (P,3), (M,3). \\
\end{align}$$

The edges are 
$$\begin{align}
&(H,0)(B1,0), (B1,0)(Bus,0), (Bus,0)(P,0), (P,0)(M,0), (H,0)(B2,0) \\
&(H,1)(B1,1), (B1,1)(Bus,1), (Bus,1)(P,1), (P,1)(M,1), (H,1)(B2,1) \\
&(H,2)(B1,2), (B1,2)(Bus,2), (Bus,2)(P,2), (P,2)(M,2), (H,2)(B2,2) \\
&(H,3)(B1,3), (B1,3)(Bus,3), (Bus,3)(P,3), (P,3)(M,3), (H,3)(B2,3) \\
&(H,0)(B1,1), (Bus,0)(B1,1), (H,0)(B2,1) \\
&(Bus,1)(P,2), (M,1)(P,2)\\
&(P,2)(M,3)\\
\end{align}$$

> What does it really mean "between $(u, i)$ and $(v, i + 1)$ if $(u, v)$ is an edge of $G$ and $v\in S_{i+1}$" ?

It means exactly what it means.

For $i=0$, $v$ must be one of two nodes in $S_{0+1}=S_1$, i.e., $B1$ and $B2$.

- If $v$ is $B1$, $u$ must be either $H$ or $Bus$ since all edges in $G$ whose endpoints include $B1$ are $HB1$ and $BusB1$. So $(H,0)(B1,1)$ and $(Bus,0)(B1,1)$ are edges in $G'$.
- If $v$ is $B2$, $u$ must be $H$ since the only edge in $G$ whose endpoints include $B2$ is $HB2$. So $(H,0)(B2,1)$ is an edge of $G'$.

It should be clear now what should happen if $i=1$ or $i=2$. Note $i$ cannot be 3 since there is no $S_{3+1}.$

> How many new nodes do need to make, 3 or 4 copies ? I only make 3 so far since there are only 3 errands.

Yes, besides the $G$ itself, we should make 3 copies of $G$, one copy of $G$ for each shop John should visit. There should be 4 copies of $G$ with 6 extra (red) edges.

Comment: The example you gave on edges is not completed, right? following your example on B1,  we can say that 
If v is P, u must be either Bus or M since all edges in G whose endpoints include P are BusP and MP . So (Bus,0)(P,1) and (M,0)(P,1) are edges in G′.

Comment: You are almost correct. For $i=1$, we have $(Bus,1)(P,2)$ and $(M,1)(P,2)(P,2)$ instead of $(Bus,0)(P,1)$ and $(M,0)(P,1)$. For $i=2$, we have $(P,2)(M,3)$.

Comment: we can say that 

If v is P, u must be either Bus or M since all edges in G whose endpoints include P are BusP and MP . So (Bus,1)(P,0) and (M,1)(P,0) are edges in G′.

If v is bus, u must be either B1 or P since all edges in G whose endpoints include P are B1Bus and PBus . So (Bus,0)(B1,1) and (Bus,0)(P,1) are edges in G′.

Comment: Please pay attention to the value of $i$. If $v$ is $P$, then $i+1$ must be 2 since $P\in S_2$ only. That is, $i$ must be 1. When we materialize "between $(u,i)$ and $(v,i+1)$ if $(u,v)$ is an edge of $G$ and $v\in S_{i+1}$", the same value of $i$ must be assigned to each appearance of $i$, just as the same value of $u$ must be assigned to each appearance of $u$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't think you are wrong this time, You said "For i=0, v must be one of two nodes in S0+1=S1, i.e., B1 and B2."  When i =0, v could be H, B1, B2, Bus, P, and M

Comment: If $i=0$, "between $(u,i)$ and $(v,i+1)$ if $(u,v)$ is an edge of $G$ and $v\in S_{i+1}$" becomes "between $(u,0)$ and $(v,1)$ if $(u,v)$ is an edge of $G$ and $v\in S_1$". **Please note the part $v\in S_1$**. (Otherwise, what is use of $v\in S_{i+1}$?)

Comment: Can you please point out what really set $S_{1}$  has ? and why H, Bus, P and M are not the members of the set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88998/discussion-between-dmomo-and-apass-jack).